# Is this regarded a duplicate on SF?

Tags: support, specific-question

Just out of interest - I'm not looking to get the poor guy's question closed, just to get a feel for things on server fault - would

[this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/130266/whats-the-best-programs-used-to-recover-a-deleted-pst-file)

normally be considered a duplicate of

[this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/50935/need-decent-undelete-utility-for-windows)

on SF?

Because on SO, it probably would.

I'm not a 3k+ user on SF so I can't see how many close votes there are in place (which is really, really a missing feature by the way IMO. One should be able to see that kind of information.)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's a dupe.  It currently has 4 close votes (mine being the first) to move to SU where it really belongs.  So it'll get moved instead of closed as a dupe.  Your comment was good to point out the dupe in this situation.  It'll probably get closed as a dupe on SU as well, since Kara pointed out a simiar question in a comment on the SF question you linked to.

Comment: Cheers @squillman. Makes sense.

Comment: hooray for linking comments.  thanks @Pekka for bringing it up, and squillman and kara for pointing out the SU dupe.